# JIRA - Add comment to issue as another user using SOAP, suds, and python

Tags: python, soap, jira, suds

I am looking for a way to add comment as another user. REST API has no such way
but SOAP has according from https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Jira-REST-API-create-a-comment-as-another-user/qaq-p/481139

Fortunately, my team still has not upgraded to 7.0 and seems no plan to upgrade since we are using SOAP in some processes.

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('https://example.com/jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl')
auth = client.service.login('jira-admin', 'jira-admin123')
client.service.addComment(auth, 'ISSUE-123', {'author': 'sample_user', 'body': 'TEST'})
```

user 'jira-admin' belong to global group 'jira-administrator' but this code is not working at all. Is there any wrong with the code or user permission?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Where did u read that version 7.0 supports that feature?

Comment: SOAP is removed in 7.0. We have no plans to upgrade our JIRA (on-premise)